# How to use values of a hash dynamically?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, mysql2, ruby-hash

Goal: Use unique email address in email header To: field (see message_class) of MIME Html Message.

**File: database.rb** Here I connect to the database and I loop through the rows in table `rcpt`. Then I store the value in `row["email"]`.

```
require 'mysql2'

class Db

  def con
    @db_host = "localhost"
    @db_user = "root"
    @db_pass = "password"
    @db_name = "table_db"

    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => @db_host, :unsername => @db_user, :password => @db_pass, :database => @db_name)
    rcpt = client.query("SELECT * from rcpt")
    rcpt.each do |row|
      row["email"]
    end
  end
end
```

Ouput of `con` method without ["email"]:

```
{"id"=>01, "email"=>"example1@example.com"}
{"id"=>02, "email"=>"example2@example.com"}
```

Output of `con` method with ["email"]:

```
example1@example.com
example2@example.com
```

DB Schema:

```
mysql> describe rcpt;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email | varchar(150) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**File: message_class.rb** Here I create the method `pull_rcpt` which then stores `row["email"]`. Then I'm trying to use the `pull_rcpt` method in `message` heredoc. Now comes my problem: in the `To:` field, I'm trying to pass the users email address I'm currently sending to, so it should change with the receiving email address. It still uses the email address of the first contact in the array/Db. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'dkim'
require './database'

class Email

  def pull_rcpt
    rcpt = Db.new
    rcpt.con
  end

  def data
    Dkim::domain      = 'example.com'
    Dkim::selector    = 'mail'
    Dkim::private_key = open('/path/to/keys/example.com/mail.private').read 

    message = <<~MESSAGE
    From: Eva <test@example.com>
    To: Dani <#{pull_rcpt[0]["email"]}>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    Subject: Test Subject

    This is an email message.
    <h1>Test</h1>
    MESSAGE
   end
end
```

**File: mailer_class.rb** In my mailer_class I have two method's `rcpt_to` and `message`. Rcpt_to contains an array `contacts`, which holds the values of `row["email"]`. Message builds the email.

```
require './database'
require './message_class'

def rcpt_to
#conn zu DB & take rcpt
  contacts = []
  contacts = Db.new
  contacts.con
end

def message 
#message
  message = Email.new
end
```

A few lines later inside a `for loop` I use the methods as follows:

```
 for rcpt in rcpt_to do
  @protocol = { ehlo: "ehlo", mail_from: "eva@example.com", rcpt_to: [rcpt["email"]], data: Dkim.sign(message.data) }
 end
```

Here is the header of example2@example.com which is the second record in the database:

```
 From: Eva <test@example.com>
 To: Dani <example1@example.com> <--- This should be example2(value in hash of second entry in database) not example1
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
 Subject: Test Subject
 Content-Length: 40
```

So the only thing not working is the dynamic To: field in the email header. The rest is just working fine and all records in the database receive an email.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. Your example is not complete (it requires a database, but you haven't provided the scheme) and it is probably not minimal (I highly doubt, you need 50 lines to demonstrate the problem).

Comment: I've updated the DB schema.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - this: `#{pull_rcpt[0]["email"]}`. You explicitly tell it to always use email of the first row.

Comment: That `rcpt.each do |row|` does not return what you think it does.

Comment: Should I use rcpt.each_with_index {|(key, value), index| }?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, this line is the core of the problem: `<#{pull_rcpt[0]["email"]}>`. You are explicitly selecting the first element in the database. To create the header dynamically, you will have to pass an argument to the data-method.

So here's one way to solve this:

In class Email, change `def data` to `def data(dynamic_email)`, and 
`To: Dani <#{pull_rcpt[0]["email"]}>` to `To: Dani <#{dynamic_email}>`

and within the loop:
`data: Dkim.sign(message.data)` => `data: Dkim.sign(message.data(rcpt["email"]))`

Something like that should work.

As a side note, your code could do some refactoring. For example, the con-method you have written doesn't work the way you think. "each" returns the array itself. If you put it on the last line of a method like that, it doesn't serve any purpose. In this case, it would be equivalent to writing `return rcpt`. If you want the method to return an array of email addresses, you should use map instead of each (or even better, rewrite your sql query). But of course, if you change that, it'll break the rest of your code. The lazy solution is just to remove the each-loop...

Comment: Thank you very much an491445!! The lazy version works, but now I'm spurred, whats the most efficient approach in your opinion? I guess to refactor the database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, as the rcpt-table only has two rows, I guess this won't do much for the efficiency, but as you asked... I got the impression that you want con to return an array of email addresses, and not an array of hashes. Changing each to map would solve that. You could also look if client.query can accept other arguments. Changing `SELECT * from rcpt` to `SELECT email from rcpt` would be a start, but I guess that it would still give you an array of hashes. Anyway, if you change what con returns, you will have to modify the rest of the code. For example `rcpt['email']` => `rcpt` within the loop.